# How can I programmatically activate the JavaScript behaviour of dynamically added html snippets in Tw-Elements (a Tailwind CSS library)?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I'm currently looking at using [TW-Elements](https://tw-elements.com/) (a UI library based on Tailwind CSS) to for a client-side serverless web application.

It works as expected, except for when the html snippet is added dynamically. Then I noticed that modals do not open and dropdowns do not drop.

I'm using the UMD version where the library is included in script tag in index.html like so:

`src="/node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/tw-elements.umd.min.js"`

I have an example dropdown markup (apologies, it's humongous bulky!):

```
<div class="relative" data-te-dropdown-ref>
    <button class="flex items-center whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-primary px-4 pb-[5px] pt-[6px] text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-normal text-white shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_#3b71ca] transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-600 hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:bg-primary-600 focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-700 active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] motion-reduce:transition-none" type="button" id="dropdownMenuSmallButton" data-te-dropdown-toggle-ref aria-expanded="false" data-te-ripple-init data-te-ripple-color="light">
        <span id="loggedInUserName">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <span class="ml-2 w-2">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
        </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="absolute z-[1000] float-left m-0 hidden min-w-max list-none overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-none bg-white bg-clip-padding text-left text-base shadow-lg dark:bg-neutral-700 [&[data-te-dropdown-show]]:block" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuSmallButton" data-te-dropdown-menu-ref>
        <li>
            <a class="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent px-4 py-2 text-sm font-normal text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 active:text-neutral-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600" href="#" data-te-dropdown-item-ref>My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent px-4 py-2 text-sm font-normal text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 active:text-neutral-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600" href="#" data-te-dropdown-item-ref>Sign Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the above markup exists in index.html ab initio, it works well. After page load, if I do:

```
document.getElementById('dropwrap').innerHTML = dropMarkup;
```

The dropdown does show up, but does not drop.

How can I programmatically activate the JS behaviour of dynamically added html in this situation?

I have pored endlessly through the documentation with no luck. I could see an `initTE` method and was wishing I could do: `initTE( document.getElementById('dropwrap')-or whatever, ...)` but that did not work.

Comment: I've never used TW-Elements before, but if there is an `initTE`, logically it means it initializes a library which recognizes the current state of a DOM so it can work with.
That means if you add new elements manually after that, TW is not aware of them, so it cannot work with them. Did you tried to reinitialize the library `initTE` after having added new elements ? This way it TW will re-recognize the whole DOM with new elements included.